# Parameterized Insert statement with transaction throwing an error

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I had a parametrized insert statement that was working well and I needed to add a select statement and wrap it all in a transaction in order to get data for one of the fields for the insert.  I'm not sure if I've hit a limitation with ASP/ADO or if I've just got something syntactically wrong.  Here's my code:

```
set oSQLCommand = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
with oSQLCommand
   .ActiveConnection = conn
   .CommandType = 1
   .CommandText = "set nocount on " &_
               "begin transaction " &_
                  "declare @docid integer " &_
                  "begin " &_
                     "set @docid = (SELECT MAX(id+1) AS docid FROM draft_main) " &_
                     "INSERT INTO draft_details (id, main_id, blah) " &_
                     "VALUES ( ?, @docid, ?)" &_
                  "end " &_
               "commit"
   .Parameters(0).value = c_id
   .Parameters(1).value = "blah blah"
   .execute
end with
set oSQLCommand = nothing
```

When I run that code, I get this error message that's triggered when it tries to set the value of Parameter(0)

```
    Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server (0x80004005)
    Syntax error or access violation
```

Any idea what's wrong?

I have plenty of experience with ASP and SQL but none with stored procedures.  Is this code so painfully close to a stored procedure I should just move it over and call it good?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting ; after each individual statement.
e.g.

```
 .CommandText = "set nocount on; " &_
               "begin transaction; " &_
                  "declare @docid integer; " &_
                  "begin " &_
                     "set @docid = (SELECT MAX(id+1) AS docid FROM draft_main); " &_
                     "INSERT INTO draft_details (id, main_id, blah) " &_
                     "VALUES ( ?, @docid, ?);" &_
                  "end ;" &_
               "commit;"
```

Comment: Also, this would be better as a call to a stored proc. Embedded SQL is evil :)

Comment: On second thoughts, are you sure? There are a bunch of individual statements in there that need to be delimited somehow. It's a while since I've done classic asp or used the ADODB 0bject directly, but I would have thought it still required delimiting.

Comment: No problem... It should still be a stored proc though ;)